# Syntactic congruence and Myhill Nerode equivalence

Tags: formal-languages

What is the difference between these two demonstrated by a concrete example? I mean I know the definitions of them, and I know that former implies latter, and intuitively I believe this, but I don't have a good example in mind at the moment that stresses out the difference. Do you know one? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $L\subseteq\{0,1\}^*$ be defined by the regular expression $(0+1)^*11$, let $x=01$, and let $y=1$. Then $x$ and $y$ are Myhill-Nerode equivalent: for any $w\in\{0,1\}^*$, $xw$ ends in $11$ if and only if $yw$ ends in $11$. However, $x$ and $y$ are not syntactically equivalent: if $u=1$ and $v=\lambda$ (the empty word), then $uxv=101\notin L$, but $uyv=11\in L$.

Comment: with (0+1)∗11 you mean: sigma*11 ? so everything that ends by 11

Comment: @user3435407: I distinguish between regular *expressions* and regular *sets*; $(0+1)^*$ (or in other notations $(0\lor 1)^*$ or $(0\cup 1)^*$) is the regular expression representing the regular set $\Sigma^*$. Thus, you’re probably interpreting it correctly, but I prefer to keep the two ideas separate in the notation.

Comment: ok, since than I found an example too, but this is a nice simple one, thx!

Comment: @user3435407: You’re welcome!